# right position and scroll bar in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

If I animate a div position right it makes a strange movement. It only happens in Firefox, if I have a div positioned right, and if there is a scroll bar. Why does it happen and how can I solve it?

- Only Firefox
- right position
- with scrollbar

Here the example simplified to check: http://jsfiddle.net/LhAEh/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#red {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px; right: 25px;
    width:80px; height:50px;
    cursor:pointer; 
    background:red;
}

#blue {/*this div is just to create a scroll*/
    margin:0 auto;
    width:80px; height:500px;
    background:blue;
}
```

jQUERY:

```
$(function(){

    $("#red").click(function() {
        $("#red").animate({bottom:'-80px'},1000);
    });

})
```

Comment: Try `position: absolute;`.

Comment: It works with positon absolute. Thank you!. Do you know why?

Comment: I **assume** that jQuery's `animate()` changes position to `absolute` before starting the animation, which then causes Firefox to move object a bit, instead of leaving it where it was.

Comment: You should put that as an answer. I would accepted as right answer and you would get the points!

Comment: I just did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `position: absolute;`.

Additional explanation: I **assume** that jQuery's `animate()` changes position to `absolute` before starting the animation, which then causes Firefox to move object a bit, instead of leaving it where it was.